# MVC CSS style not accepted

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im developed the MVC project , I want to style this display error message but its not working,i cant add this for **CSS** style ,How can i do it?

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.SelectedValue)
```

CSS

```
.field-validation-error {
    color: #ff0000;
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    top: 5px;  font-size:14px; font-family:'Arno Pro';
    width: 250px; /*background:url(../img/wrng_icn.png) no-repeat right center;
}
```

Comment: can you show rendered html from your `ValidationMessageFor`?

Comment: Did you add jquery-validation.css properly?

Comment: yeah im added     <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign custom attributes to Html Helpers like the below.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.SelectedValue, new {@class = "field-validation-error"});
```

Update:
Pass it a null to use a different overload

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.SelectedValue, null, new {@class = "field-validation-error"});
```

Comment: @DavidG Please explain why? The answer is correct, it has fixed the OP's issue, isn't that the point of accepting an answer. Some newer users do not understand the concept of accepting answers. Otherwise this question will look unanswered. I never asked for upvotes.

Comment: omg its not working correctly, having erros, cant add for your solution,

Comment: @AlberttheCoder Why is it not working, just a minute ago you said `thanks for the help its working` what has changed?

Comment: not complied thid code, @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.SelectedValue, new {@class = "field-validation-error"});  its not working sir

Comment: @JamieR Because it looks like begging. Let the answer stand for itself and the OP can decide if he/she wants to accept. On the subject of educating new users, it's *sometimes* OK to say things like "don't forget to accept/upvote any answers or questions that you find useful on Stackoverflow" but generally it's bad. See [this link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266311/polite-way-to-request-an-answer-be-reviewed-by-an-asker/266312#266312)

Comment: im very very sorry for my big issue , thats my falt

Comment: i got that error Line 106:         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.SelectedValue, new { @class = "field-validation-error" });

Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Comment: @Jamie R,
Sir finaly its working , thanks for your big help, im remove the semicolon ,now its working your second solution, thank you, im new beginner :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92238/discussion-between-albert-the-coder-and-jamie-r).